# jQuery Popup Datepicker Inside a Modal Doesn't Maintain Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, accessibility

I'm trying to augment an accessible datepicker popup to my modal view. Clicking the 'Timecard Form' opens the modal. Use tabs inside the modal. When the calendar icon is in focus, spacebar will open the calendar popup. While inside this popup, I should be able to use tabbing to access the month selection icons, days or close button and then return to select, i.e., the tab order should wrap inside the calendar popup. I should also be able to use the arrow keys to step through the days once they're in focus. All of this works when I use the datepicker outside of the modal. When I put the datepicker inside the modal, the calendar can't maintain focus and tabbing closes the popup.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this bit of code:

```
  // Hide the entire page (except the date picker)
  // from screen readers to prevent document navigation
  // (by headings, etc.) while the popup is open
  $("main").attr('id','dp-container');
  $("#dp-container").attr('aria-hidden','true');
  $("#skipnav").attr('aria-hidden','true');
```

I had some difficulty pulling all the parts together in jsfiddle so here is a url to the example:  http://lucillekenney-demos.com/sass-muse/time2.html

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I'm not using the Bootstrap datepicker as I'm told it is not so accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your guess that the aria-hidden code is causing this issue is incorrect, I believe. The aria-hidden attribute should have no effect on a keyboard user, only a screen reader user. A keyboard user can still access an element with the aria-hidden attribute.